# How to compare more than two strings?

Tags: java

```
 if ((A!= null || A!= "") && (B!= null || B!= "")
                && (C!= null || C!= "")elseif...elseif...elseif...
```

How we can do this without if else condition or in minimum code ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Well, using `!=` is *also* a problem with the sample code, but not really the gist of the question.

Comment: dont use equals, you are comparing references with that....

Comment: There's no way to do that sort of test on lots of strings at once.  What you have is what I'd write.

Comment: @kartik Any time you find yourself doing something like this, you need to go back and evaluate the underlying data structure, since you're probably doing something wrong.  For instance, in this case, why do you have so many individual variables at all?  Why aren't all your strings in a list, so you can loop through and only write the comparison logic once?

Comment: Did you mean `A!= null` _**`&&`**_ `A!= ""`?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a `List<String>` and any number could be `null` or empty you can do

```
List<String> values = ...
List<String> good = values.stream()
                          .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Instead of having lots of variables, you are better off having an appropriate collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would group all the strings in a stream and then apply the same logic to each element:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of(a, b, c, ...);

if (strings.allMatch(s -> s != null || s != "")) {
    //
}
```

Note: I've changed variable names to a, b, c, etc., since Java conventions  establish that variable names should be lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Please [don't compare](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/466738) `s != ""`. Use `equals()` or `isEmpty()`.